# Problema para funcionar dois efeitos prontos Jquery no site. os dois ficam estáticos, não funcionam

Tags: jquery

Olá. estou fazendo um portfolio e estou com problema para fazer funcionar dois efeitos jQuery que eu retirei e modifiquei destes sites, um menu dinâmico < http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/12/animated-text-and-icon-menu/ > e um slide de imagens carousel < http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/Image-Scale-Carousel/ >. O menu dinâmico sozinho funciona normalmente, mas quando eu vou colocar o código do carousel nem o menu e nem o carousel funcionam. o menu fica estático, e o carousel fica com um quadrado preto aonde era para ser as imagens. Não sei se é problema de conflito com os jQuery, porque eu tentei colocar o código no conflict no e não deu certo. Gostaria de saber o que tem que ser feito para funcionar os dois efeitos. Obrigado, fico no aguardo.

Jquery do menu:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#sti-menu').iconmenu();
        });
    </script>
```

Jquery do carousel:

```
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>google.load("jquery", "1");</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libisc.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQueryisc/jQuery.isc.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<script src="jQueryisc/jquery-image-scale-carousel.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var carousel_images = [
        "imagesisc/01.jpg",
        "imagesisc/02.jpg",
        "imagesisc/03.jpg",
        "imagesisc/04.jpg",
        "imagesisc/05.jpg",
        "imagesisc/06.jpg",
    ];

    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#photo_container").isc({
            imgArray: carousel_images
        });    
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Parceiro, você usa o firebug ou algum plugin similar? Veja se aparece algum erro no console quando você executa a página.

Comment: No console do firebug quando eu testo os efeitos separados não aparece nenhuma mensagem. mas quando eu vou testar no meu portfolio com os dois efeitos inclusos diz o seguinte no jquery do menu, que seria o primeiro box acima: TypeError: $(...).iconmenu is not a function. Não entendo direito o que quis dizer esta mensagem, não sei se é isso que não esta deixando os jquerys funcionar. Qual é a maneira certa de se fazer funcionar dois efeitos prontos no Jquery, que sejam ao menos um menu e um slide.

Comment: O jQuery as vezes é meio chato, ele exige que esteja tudo certinho. Tente colocar os scripts juntos dentro do document ready: $(document).ready(function(e) {

  //Iniciando o Menu
  $('#sti-menu').iconmenu();
 
  //Criando o carrosel
  var carousel_images = [
   "imagesisc/01.jpg",
   "imagesisc/02.jpg",
   "imagesisc/03.jpg",
   "imagesisc/04.jpg",
   "imagesisc/05.jpg",
   "imagesisc/06.jpg",
  ];

  $("#photo_container").isc({
   imgArray: carousel_images
  });    

    });

Comment: Inclua o html à pergunta com a forma como você está aplicando os scripts